# Divide each element of an array by each element of an other array

Tags: python, numpy, division

I'm coding a function that tells which numbers are prime numbers in a given array.
I would also like to do it without a for loop if it is possible

The `numpy.divide` function and division symbole (`/`) do not work as they throw a ValueError because the two arrays do not have the same shape

```py
numbers = np.array([2, 3, 6])

def prime(numbers):
    biggest = np.max(numbers)
    division_array = np.arange(2, ceil(biggest / 2) + 1)
    # division_array = [2, 3]
    return numbers / division_array

print(numbers)
```

Expected output:

```
[[1, 0.6],
 [1.5, 1],
 [3, 2]]
```

Output:

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,) (3,)

Comment: So, by your (apparent) reasoning, dividing a 3-element array by another should produce a 3x3 array of results?

Comment: Add a new axis to `numbers` to use [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html): `return numbers[:, np.newaxis] / division_array`

Comment: @ScottHunter No but a 3-element array by a 2-element array should produce a 3x2 array, not a 3x3.

Comment: @jdehesa Thanks it work, could you put it as an answer so that i accept it.

Comment: `np.divide.outer([2, 3, 6], [2, 3])`

Comment: @user3483203 Thanks, very compact, but I already accepted a answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want an "all-to-all" operation, the best thing is to [broadcast](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) the arrays. Maybe the easiest way is to add a dimension to `numbers` with `np.newaxis` and divide:

```
import numpy as np

numbers = np.array([2, 3, 6])

def prime(numbers):
    biggest = np.max(numbers)
    division_array = np.arange(2, np.ceil(biggest / 2) + 1)
    # division_array = [2, 3]
    return numbers[:, np.newaxis] / division_array

print(prime(numbers))
# [[1.         0.66666667]
#  [1.5        1.        ]
#  [3.         2.        ]]
```

Comment: Thanks, you just reminded me of how I did it : I reshaped it to a Nx1 array

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who doesn't want to use numpy, I created a plain python function for this.

I created this function that you could use to get what you need:
https://repl.it/repls/ImpartialVainWebsites

```
array1 = [2, 3, 6]
array2 = [2, 3]

def divide_array(array1, array2):
  new_array = list()
  for element in array1:
    array1_list = list()
    for element2 in array2:
      array1_list.append(round(element/element2, 3))
    new_array.append(array1_list)
  return new_array

print(divide_array(array1, array2))
```

Returns:

```
[[1.0, 0.667], [1.5, 1.0], [3.0, 2.0]]
```

Or in a more compact form:

```
array1 = [2, 3, 6]
array2 = [2, 3]

def divide_array(array1, array2):
  new_array = list()
  for element in array1:
    new_array.append([round(element/element2, 3) for element2 in array2])
  return new_array

print(divide_array(array1, array2))
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it without a for loop ? I know i did it before but i forgot how...

Comment: @Docaro I changed it to use list comprehension, would that work better for you?

Comment: Not really as it is still a for loop so for really big lists it will take a long time

Comment: Okay I guess, I'll just keep the answer as it as for people in the future who might want to do it without numpy

Comment: Thanks anyway for helping :)